# Translating the definition of closure into a set

Tags: general-topology, elementary-set-theory

I'm trying to translate the following sentence into set builder notation.

"The $\mathbf{T}$-closure of a set $S$
  consists of all points p
  such that every member of $\mathbf{T}$ containing p
  meets $S$"

My guesses are below. The last 3 are equivalent (eliminating a bounded quantifier and using [exportation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exportation_(logic))),

$cl(S)=\{p:(\forall T\in\mathbf{T})(p\in T) T\cap S\neq\emptyset\}$

The above line was my first guess, but the more I thought about how quantified statements over predicates work, I realized that having the $T\cap S \neq \emptyset $ out of the predicate didnt make sense, so I came up with the followng:

\begin{align} cl(S) &=\{p:(\forall T\in\mathbf{T})(p\in T \implies T\cap S\neq\emptyset)\} \\
&= \{p:(\forall T\in\mathbf{T})(p\notin T \lor T\cap S\neq\emptyset)\} \\
&= \{p:(\forall T)(T\in\mathbf{T} \implies (p\in T \implies T\cap S\neq\emptyset)) \} \\
&= \{p:(\forall T)((T\in\mathbf{T} \land p\in T) \implies T\cap S\neq\emptyset) \} \\ \end{align}

Comment: The last of the equivalent statements using negatives seems unnatural. Use the first. Why no $p \in X$ or whatever the set is we are working in?

Comment: Yes, its totally unnatural. I Included it since its easy to compute (since it doesn't involve an implication), although retrospectivley, $cl(S) =\{p:(\forall T\in\mathbf{T})(p\notin T \lor T\cap S\neq\emptyset)\}$ is both clearer and has the same benefit, so I'll replace it. I left the universal set unspecified since a sets closure obviously depends on the topology $(X,\mathbf{T})$, and thus it is clear $p\in X$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems indeed that your last ones are all equivalent (based on commmon sense). I would personally put it as (the total underlying set I will denote $X$ and the topological space $(X,\mathcal{T})$

$$\operatorname{cl}(S) = \{p \in X: \forall O \in \mathcal{T}: (p \in O) \rightarrow (O \cap S \neq \emptyset)\}$$ making explicit the total space (as we use comprehension, we can only build subsets of already given sets).

Comment: Is it acceptable to have two ":" in a set definition? Also isn't this equivalent to $cl(S) =\{p \in X:(\forall T\in\mathbf{T})(p\in T \implies T\cap S\neq\emptyset)\} $, (which is in prenex normal form)?

Comment: The first is the separator really. As in: if $\phi(x,y_1,\ldots, y_n)$ is some formula and $S$ is a set then $\{x \in S: \phi(x, z_1, \ldots , z_n)\}$ is a set too. Where I put brackets is for comprehension only. I do mean that $\forall O$ applies to the whole implication.